# How to export HTMLElement into <script>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-component, vercel

Hi I have a project in NextJs, where I use app router. In my public folder I have a file called chatbutton.js, I need this button to work as a web component that I can implement on external websites.

Implement like this:

```
<script>
window.embeddedChatbotConfig = {
chatId: "fUYYCegK9QYOtoGJ25Dv1",
domain: "www.chatai.com"
}
</script>
<script
src="https://www.chatai.com/chatbutton.min.js"
chatbotId="fUYYCegK9QYOtoGJ25Dv1"
domain="www.chatai.com"
defer>
</script>
```

public/chatbutton.min.js:

```
class ChatButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Create shadow DOM
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    // Initialize the component
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    // Create chat button
    const chatButton = document.createElement("div");
    chatButton.setAttribute("id", "chatbase-bubble-button");
    chatButton.style.position = "fixed";
    chatButton.style.bottom = "20px";
    chatButton.style.right = "20px";
...
    chatButton.appendChild(chatButtonIcon);

    // Add click event listener
    chatButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleChatWindow());

    // Append chat button to shadow DOM
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(chatButton);

    // Create chat window
    const chat = document.createElement("div");
    chat.setAttribute("id", "chatbase-bubble-window");
    chat.style.position = "fixed";
    chat.style.flexDirection = "column";
    chat.style.justifyContent = "space-between";
    chat.style.bottom = "80px";
    chat.style.zIndex = 999999999;

    // Append iframe to chat window
    chat.innerHTML = `<iframe src="https://www.chatai.com/chatbot-iframe/${this.getAttribute(
      "data-chatbotId"
    )}" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`;

    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(chat);

    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 550px)");

    function handleChatWindowSizeChange(t) {
      t.matches && ((chat.style.height = "600px"), (chat.style.width = "400px"));
    }

    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleChatWindowSizeChange);
    handleChatWindowSizeChange(mediaQuery);
  }

  toggleChatWindow() {
    const chat = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("chatbase-bubble-window");
    chat.style.display = chat.style.display === "none" ? "flex" : "none";
  }

  get CHAT_BUTTON_ICON() {
    return `
      <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M20 2H4C2.9 2 2 2.9 2 4V22L6 18H20C21.1 18 22 17.1 22 16V4C22 2.9 21.1 2 20 2ZM20 16H6L4 18V4H20V16Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      </svg>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("chatbase-bubble", ChatBaseBubble);
```

I need this implementation to be able to add a button that shows an iframe with my chat. But when I add the url to my script, the botton and iframe are not displayed. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: hey.. can you share any sample repo with a basic implementation of web-component with this package: @r2wc/react-to-web-component